# Cannot enable viewstate?

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I have a web apllication with wizard control with 4 step index. Each having a dynamically editable grid which need to put only valid data & goto next.

In one step which have 2 columns which are not require to be editable because it has set its value from previous field by calculation, done with javascript.

But problem is that when we decalre these field as a enable false or read only mode then it works but can not able maintain state means its value goes off when we change the step index changed. (If that field are editable then it works ok.)

Also I tried it by use of label field but the same thing happen when the step changes label can not maintan its state (its value clears when step changes).

Please give me idea how to resolve this problem. Also each step has a dynamically created editable grid.

Thanks & Regards,
     Girish

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your javascript is doing the calculation from another field that is set by the user, then why couldn't you just redo that calculation on the server side when switching to the next step.  I am assuming that the "value from previous field" is getting passed back to the server.

Another solution would be to have your javascript populate a hidden field too (in addition to the one viewable by the user).  Then you just read that hidden field.